# Select some entries of a matrix given an indexing matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have two matrices, let's say `A` and my indexing matrix, `I`, and where its value is 1, I want to take the value of the matrix `A` of the same position, and where its value is 0, I want to put a 0 in the position of the matrix `A`.

For example:

```
A=

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

I=

0 1 0

0 0 1

1 1 0
```

So my desired output would be:

```
0 2 0

0 0 6

7 8 0
```

I know I can do it with two `for` loops, but it's no very efficient. Is there a better way? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're guaranteed that they'll be 0 and 1 in your indexing matrix, check out element-by-element multiplication: http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/times.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `I` is only `1` and `0`, just write `A.*I`:

```
ans =
     0     2     0
     0     0     6
     7     8     0
```

If `I` has some other numbers, then the general case for keeping only the elements in `A` where `I` in the same position in `k` would be:

```
A = magic(3)
I = [1 2 3
    3 2 1
    2 1 3]
k = 1;
A.*(I==k)
```

And the output:

```
A =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
I =
     1     2     3
     3     2     1
     2     1     3
ans =
     8     0     0
     0     0     7
     0     9     0
```

And this, of course, could be altered to `I>k` or `I<=(k+5)` or any other logical statement you wish.
The key here is that `(I==k)` yields a logical output:

```
ans =
     1     0     0
     0     0     1
     0     1     0
```

which brings us back to the first case.

Answer (score 1):

You can invert the indexing matrix (this will implicitly convert to binary if it was not binary yet), and set the value at those indices to zero.

```
 A(~I) = 0
```

Advantage is that you do not really need to define new or additional matrices, which is expensive if your matrix is large.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the best approach in your case is simple term by term multiplication. In a more complicated case, where you have to change the entries according to a rule that depends on your indexing matrix, you can access the entries pointed by your indexing matrix.

For example, if you want to double one-indexed entries and set zero-indexed entries to -1, you should do:

```
A(I==1)=2*A(I==1);
A(I==0)=-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I greatly prefer @EBH's answer but here is another way of doing it by using `logical`:

```
B = zeros(size(A));
log_I = logical(I);
B(log_I) = A(log_I);
B

B =

     0     2     0
     0     0     6
     7     8     0
```